# Homotopies and simply connectedness

Tags: complex-analysis

**QUESTION:** If we are given a space $X=\mathbb{C}$ that is simply connected and two points, call them $a,b \in X$, and two curves $f,g:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ such that $f(0)=g(0)=a$ and $f(1)=g(1)=b$, can we say that there exists a homotopy that is completely contained in the space between the curves $f$ and $g$, inclusive?

Comment: What do you mean by the space between the curves?

Comment: The space enclosed by the two curves, including the boundary formed by the curves.

Comment: Do you want $f$ and $g$ to be injective? If the image of the curves is self-intersecting it's no longer clear what you mean.

Comment: Yes, we can assume they are injective(simple curves).

Comment: Then the answer is yes; one approach is to apply the Schoenflies theorem.

Comment: Alright, thanks.